# Crystal Reports: X/Y axis Label orientation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am generating a line chart/graph by fetching data from the database. I want to change the orientation of the labeling from horizontal to vertical on the x-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the graph and then right-click on one of the x-axis labels.
2. Pick "Format Axis Label"
3. On the Font tab, there is a Rotation option... set to 90 degrees. Done!

[image]